# iPhone - Inertial dragging

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an object that the user has to drag around the screen. This is a regular UIImageView. Currently, the image can be dragged around but when you release it, it stops where your finger lifted the image. What I want is to create momentum, so I can give an impulse to the image and it scrolls until it bounces the screen edge.

I don't want nothing very complex like adding physics libraries and stuff like that. I want to keep it as minimum as possible.

How do I do that? Can you guys point me to some tutorial or in the right direction?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well one way of doing this without using any physics library is this:

First in your class create 4 instance variables like this:

```
CFTimeInterval startTime;
CGPoint startPoint;
CGPoint oldPoint;
BOOL imageViewTouched;
```

Than in your `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method have this code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouched] anyObject];
    // Test to see if the touched view is your image view. If not just return.
    if (touch.view != <#yourImageView#>) {
        return;
    }

    startPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    oldPoint = startPoint;
    startTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    imageViewTouched = YES;
}
```

For `- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` do this:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Fingers were moved on the screen but your image view was not touched in the beginning
    if (!imageViewTouched) {
        return;
    }

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint newPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    <#yourImageView#>.frame = CGRectOffset(<#yourImageView#>.frame, newPoint.x - oldPoint.x, newPoint.y - oldPoint.y);
    oldPoint = newPoint;
}
```

Now for `- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` try this:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Fingers were removed from the screen but your image view was not touched in the beginning
    if (!imageViewTouched) {
        return;
    }

    imageViewTouched = NO;

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint endPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CFTimeInterval endTime = CACurrentMediaTime();

    CFTimeInterval timeDifference = endTime - startTime;

    // You may play with this value until you get your desired effect
    CGFloat maxSpeed = 80;

    CGFloat deltaX = 0;
    CGFloat deltaY = 0;

    if (timeDifference < 0.35) {
        deltaX = (endPoint.x - startPoint.x) / (timeDifference * 10);
        deltaY = (endPoint.y - startPoint.y) / (timeDifference * 10);
    }

    if      (deltaX > maxSpeed)         { deltaX =  maxSpeed; }
    else if (deltaX < -maxSpeed)        { deltaX = -maxSpeed; }
    else if (deltaX > -5 && deltaX < 5) { deltaX = 0; }

    if      (deltaY > maxSpeed)         { deltaY =  maxSpeed; }
    else if (deltaY < -maxSpeed)        { deltaY = -maxSpeed; }
    else if (deltaY > -5 && deltaY < 5) { deltaY = 0; }

    [UIView begginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    <#yourImageView#>.frame = CGRectOffset(<#yourImageView#>.frame, deltaX, deltaY);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Please let me know if this makes sense and/or works for you. Cheers!